# How can i create a loop to scrape multiple pages from source url using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

***The current script allows me to scrape only a single page but i would like to scarpe all 5 pages from the source url. How can i loop/iterate through remaining 4 pages?***

```
#Import Libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
source = requests.get('https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-ratings/?industry=Aerospace%20&%20Defense&currentpage=1').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

#Start CSV
csv_file = open('aerospacedata_1.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['company_name', 'company_exchange', 'company_risk'])

#Scrape Data from Web and write to csv
for company_info in soup.find_all(class_='company-row d-flex'):
    company_name = company_info.a.text
    company_exchange = company_info.find("small").text
    company_risk = company_info.find("div", class_="col-2").text
    print(company_name, company_exchange,company_risk)
    csv_writer.writerow([company_name, company_exchange, company_risk])
csv_file.close()
```

Output:

company_name    company_exchange    company_risk

AECC Aviation Power Co Ltd  SHG:600893  53.3

Airbus SE   PAR:AIR 30.3

Aselsan Elektronik Sanayi ve Ticaret AS IST:ASELS   31.6

AVIC Aircraft Co., Ltd. SHE:000768  54.4

AVIC Shenyang Aircraft Co. Ltd. SHG:600760  51.3

AviChina Industry & Technology Company Limited  HKG:2357    45.2

BAE Systems PLC LON:BA  34.3

Bombardier Inc. TSE:BBD.B   30

BWX Technologies, Inc.  NYS:BWXT    42.3

CAE Inc.    TSE:CAE 32.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `for` loop and use the loop invariable to construct the url and the file name

```
#Import Libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

pages = 5
for i in range(1, pages+1):
    print(f"Page - {i}")
    source = requests.get(f'https://www.sustainalytics.com/esg-ratings/?industry=Aerospace%20&%20Defense&currentpage={i}').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

    #Start CSV
    csv_file = open(f'aerospacedata_{i}.csv', 'w')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(['company_name', 'company_exchange', 'company_risk'])

    #Scrape Data from Web and write to csv
    for company_info in soup.find_all(class_='company-row d-flex'):
        company_name = company_info.a.text
        company_exchange = company_info.find("small").text
        company_risk = company_info.find("div", class_="col-2").text
        print(company_name, company_exchange,company_risk)
        csv_writer.writerow([company_name, company_exchange, company_risk])
    csv_file.close()

    print("---" * 30)
```

Output:

```
Page - 1
AECC Aviation Power Co Ltd SHG:600893 53.3
Airbus SE PAR:AIR 30.3
Aselsan Elektronik Sanayi ve Ticaret AS IST:ASELS 31.6
AVIC Aircraft Co., Ltd. SHE:000768 54.4
AVIC Shenyang Aircraft Co. Ltd. SHG:600760 51.3
AviChina Industry & Technology Company Limited HKG:2357 45.2
BAE Systems PLC LON:BA 34.3
Bombardier Inc. TSE:BBD.B 30
BWX Technologies, Inc. NYS:BWXT 42.3
CAE Inc. TSE:CAE 32.4
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Page - 2
China Avionics Systems Co.,Ltd. SHG:600372 54.8
Cobham PLC LON:COB 34.7
Curtiss-Wright Corp NYS:CW 39
Dassault Aviation S.A. PAR:AM 31.8
Embraer S.A. BSP:EMBR3 36.3
FACC AG WBO:FACC 37.9
General Dynamics Corp NYS:GD 37.5
Heico Corp NYS:HEI 39.3
Hexcel Corp NYS:HXL 31.6
Huntington Ingalls Industries, Inc. NYS:HII 41.3
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Page - 3
Kongsberg Gruppen ASA OSL:KOG 29
Korea Aerospace Industries, Ltd. KRX:047810 49.9
L3Harris Technologies, Inc. NYS:LHX 38.8
Leonardo S.p.a. MIL:LDO 28.7
Lockheed Martin Corp NYS:LMT 30.6
Macquarie Infrastructure Corp NYS:MIC 44.7
Meggitt PLC LON:MGGT 32.7
MTU Aero Engines AG ETR:MTX 23.8
Northrop Grumman Corp. NYS:NOC 31.1
QinetiQ Group PLC LON:QQ 23
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Page - 4
Raytheon Co NYS:RTN 32.9
Rheinmetall AG ETR:RHM 35.4
Rolls-Royce Holdings PLC LON:RR 28.6
Saab AB OME:SAAB.B 31.5
Safran SA PAR:SAF 30.7
Senior PLC LON:SNR 31.9
Signature Aviation Plc LON:SIG 35.4
Singapore Technologies Engineering Ltd. SES:S63 29.2
Spirit AeroSystems Holdings Inc NYS:SPR 36.8
Teledyne Technologies, Inc. NYS:TDY 37.5
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Page - 5
Textron Inc. NYS:TXT 37.8
Thales SA PAR:HO 28.6
The Boeing Company NYS:BA 39
TransDigm Group Inc NYS:TDG 40.9
Ultra Electronics Holdings PLC LON:ULE 37.4
United Technologies Corp NYS:UTX 29.3
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: That works perfectly, Thank you so much for your help!